# ActiveRercord: find_or_create_by_association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm wondering what would be the ideal way to find or create a nested record using something similar to the `find_or_crate` method.

For regular attributes there's the very convenient `User.find_or_create_by_attribute` method.

Is there anything for a nested association?

Let's say a `User` has a `Profile`. What would be the ideal way to find or create based on its `profile` presence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find anything sexier than `profile = user.profile || user.create_profile`.